# AV to HDMI 1080p Scaler Video Converter Outputting Sound But Not Video

Tags: monitor, nintendo-64, hdmi

I'm trying to connect my N64 to my HP 22cwa HD monitor. I'm using an Enko Products AV to HDMI 1080p Scaler Video Converter box (as the title states). I have everything plugged in, but when turn everything on, the audio comes through but not the video. The N64 works fine on my TV at home (I'm at college which is why I'm using my monitor), so it's not the N64. The monitor is supposed to automatically switch between video inputs, but when it scans for the HDMI input, it doesn't pick anything up. Based on all this, I can only assume I either am completely oblivious to something I need to do, or the HDMI cord itself is messed up (it's brand-new). Is there anything else I should check? What would be the next logical course of action in my troubleshooting?

Here's a video of someone successfully doing what I'm trying to do (albeit with a different converter box):

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about generic peripheral troubleshooting.

Comment: @Frank I don't really understand what is generic about it. While HDMI Scalars could be used for other types of devices, they are mostly used in the context of gaming. I feel that this question could provide useful information for other people having difficulty connecting their retro systems to newer HD TVs.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the console, as has been stated. HDMI scalers have many uses outside of gaming, notably DVD players. They are not gaming specific hardware.

Comment: I've found similar questions about these devices on this particular community. They never answered my specific question though, which is why I'm asking now. I posted it here and not elsewhere for the reason Hagelt18 said. There are numerous questions out there involving this kind of stuff, and they are always in the gaming section. I posted it here because I hoped that the *gaming* forum would have people knowledgeable in dealing with adapting old *gaming* consoles to new devices. If it really doesn't belong here, then can someone at least recommend the proper topic section?

Comment: The N64 works fine. That means its either the splitter, or the monitor. Either one requires non-gaming tech support.

Comment: We know the N64 works fine. But I will stand by my opinion that this technology is primarily used in gaming. How many people do you think actually buy an HDMI scalar for an old DVD player. A decent HDMI Scaler costs as much or more than a new DVD/Bluray player.

Comment: @Neonpeanut Can you test the device on a different display device?

Comment: I did. It's weird, but I do think I figured out the issue.

Comment: This is relevant, and should also fix the issue above: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/295801/has-the-composite-to-hdmi-converter-better-quality-than-composite-to-scart-to-hd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I did a little bit of digging, and it seems that I the converter I got was not what I thought it was. The one I got is apparently a very well-made copycat of the product I was trying to get. I had ordered it on Amazon, so I didn't think of the possibility of that. I ordered a new one directly from the company this time, so that should fix the problem. I guess the lesson here is to make sure the products you order have the little details that help verify its legitimacy. If I hadn't literally sat down and just looked over every bit of the device, I wouldn't have known the difference from the real thing. Anyways, I guess that solves my issue.