# Has the composite to HDMI converter better quality than composite to SCART to HDMI?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, nintendo-64, snes

I have connected Super Nintendo and Nintendo 64 to my flat screen. Currently I am connecting the composite to Scart head, which is connected to Scart to HDMI converter.

I found a RCA to HDMI converter.

I know that the biggest problem with the quality is the RCA cable itself, but having a Scart and multiple conversions sounds like a unneeded loss of quality to me.

Also, the RCA to HDMI has usb power, which might indicate an amplification. The brand of the converter is Teorder.

Should the RCA to HDMI have better quality than my current setup?

If you have better ideas for connection, feel free to introduce.

Comment: Besides the amplification, I doubt there would be much difference, as SCART is digital and so is HDMI, so as long as the signal is strong enough to pass through, there shouldn't be any loss in quality with the multiple conversions. Digital signal is great like that - it either has enough signal to work or it doesn't and it doesn't work. There is no loss in quality with digital.

Comment: @Chippies  SCART doesn't support digital video. You might be confused by the fact that it supports RGB analogue video.

Comment: @RossRidge bwah, I must have remembered it wrong. That completely invalidates everything I said then, lol

Answer (score 1):

The yellow-RCA is Composite (1ch), which is not as good as S-video (2channel - both are analog). You may need to replace the [s-video cable](http://www.mountainouswords.com/mountain-air/snes-and-the-secret-s-video/)(s) (most are DIN but SCART and DVI also support s-video), then convert to HDMI if necessary and follow up here as I'd be curious to know if you can see the difference.

If you're in the US then you probably have an NTSC system whereas PAL units were sold in the EU. Their associated SCART had [different pinouts](http://members.optusnet.com.au/eviltim/gamescart/gamescart.htm). The power is because your adapter basically has a little computer (IC) in there, and there's no 5v power from RCA. The distance of HDMI is actually shorter than analog but it has no loss (or less loss, I know some people recognize interference in longer hdmi runs but for the most part it either works or doesn't).

Comment: Just note that the super nintendo runs at 320 x 240.  There's just no way to make that look really nice at even just 480p.  You WILL get really huge blocks.

Comment: yea, with insignificant exceptions, credit Dan_Hill:

"N64 standard outputs were 240p (NTSC 320x240) and 288p (PAL 320x288), but it was capable of 480i (576i for PAL with huge borders). Most developers never used the 480i mode... The 4MB expansion pack allowed better use... The only game which did was Turok 2"